# Using USBASP programmer for SPI communication

Tags: avr, libusb, spi

I'm trying to send some data from PC to ATmega328P chip through USBASP programmer.

It is able to transmit up to 4 bytes over SPI. These 4 bytes сan be set in USB Setup Packet (2 bytes for `wValue` and 2 bytes for `wIndex`). To enable SPI in ATmega328P I've connected USBASP `Reset` pin to `SS`. At PC side I'm using `libusb` to send USB Setup Packets.

ATmega328P code:

```
int main()
{
    char spiData = 0;

    // Enable SPI
    SPCR |= 1 << SPE;
    DDRB |= 1 << 4;

    // Main cycle
    while(1)
    {
        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF))); // Wait for transmission end
        spiData = SPDR; // Read SPI Data Register
        // Do something with first byte

        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
        spiData = SPDR;
        // Do something with second byte

        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
        spiData = SPDR;
        // Do something with third byte

        while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
        spiData = SPDR;
        // Do something with fourth byte
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PC code (C#):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Find USBASP
    var device = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(new UsbDeviceFinder(0x16C0, 0x05DC));

    // Set Clock and RESET pin to enable SPI
    int bytesTrasferred;
    var usbSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket(0xC0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    device.ControlTransfer(ref usbSetupPacket, null, 0, out bytesTrasferred);

    // Send Setup Packets
    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
        usbSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket(0xC0, 3, 200, 200, 0);
        device.ControlTransfer(ref usbSetupPacket, buffer, 4, out bytesTrasferred);
        Console.WriteLine("Done. Return result: [{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3]);
    }

    // Disable SPI
    usbSetupPacket = new UsbSetupPacket(0xC0, 2, 0, 0, 0);
    device.ControlTransfer(ref usbSetupPacket, null, 0, out bytesTrasferred);

    // Free resources
    device.Close();
    UsbDevice.Exit();
}
```

USBASP -> ATmega328P SPI communication works well, but it seems that data in `wValue` and `wIndex` fields of Setup Packet comes corrupted to USBASP, because I'm getting this output (while it should be constant - [0, 200, 0, 200]):

```
[0, 153, 0, 128]
[0, 136, 0, 128]
[1, 209, 1, 217]
[1, 128, 0, 145]
[1, 153, 0, 128]
[0, 145, 1, 209]
[1, 217, 1, 136]
[0, 209, 1, 209]
[1, 217, 1, 136]
so on...
```

Also I see these numbers on LED digit display connected to ATmega328P.

Can anyone explain that?

*P.S. For programming purposes this USBASP works well.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in SPI though. My ATmega328P was set by default to 8MHz internal clock with 1/8 divider, so it had 1MHz frequency which is too small for proper SPI communication. I fixed that by setting ATmega328P to external 16mHz crystal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the data transfer rate to 750kb in libusb or if that program does not support changing transfer rates, use a program such as avrdude which can do that.